# "In-bag" for RandomForest* objects

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there some way to identify the samples that were used in constructing each tree in a `RandomForest{Classifier, Regressor}` object?

I am looking for the equivalent of "keep.inbag" in this R implementation: http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math47/R/library/randomForest/html/randomForest.html

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question (with help from @amueller on the scikit-learn mailing list - thanks!), here is a function that calculates the in-bag matrix:

```
from sklearn.ensemble.forest import _generate_sample_indices
def calc_inbag(n_samples, forest):
        n_trees = forest.n_estimators
        inbag = np.zeros((n_samples, n_trees))
        for t_idx in range(n_trees):
            sample_idx = _generate_sample_indices(forest.estimators_[t_idx].random_state, 
                                                  n_samples)
            inbag[:, t_idx] = np.bincount(sample_idx, minlength=n_samples)
        return inbag
```